# Bluetooth not connecting error

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, robotics, robot

I am making and robotic arm by using arduino and hc - 05 module and controlling that arm using mobile application now problem what i am facing is the mobile app dose not connect to bluetooth device whenever i run the following code

http://pastie.org/p/79sDLtqMdIE9xpS3RN1S3N

but when i run different code the bluetooth get connects with the app and runs withoutany error can anyone help me to figure it out

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i have learnt working with HC-05 modules is that communicates through its RX/TX lines at 9600 baud. But, if you need to send/receive AT commands, then the baud rate needs to be 38400 and needs to have the EN pin driven high on startup. I haven't checked the rest of your code, but since you are not programming using AT commands, then the baud rate needs to be set to 9600 with only VCC,GND,RX,TX lines connected to the microcontroller.

HC-05 works best with Arduino's native serial port. My personal experience is that HC-05 struggles to maintain stable connection with SoftwareSerial library. Although HC-06 works with SoftwareSerial with no problems.

Comment: i have change to 9600 still it is not working

Comment: @Muhammed, what mobile app are you using? Are you on Android or Apple?

Comment: bluetooth terminal

Comment: @Muhammed, what is this different code that makes Bluetooth work?

Comment: this code http://pastie.org/p/3OlqQnMR3VE4h4Oqs3iRHs

Comment: @Muhammed, are you using arduino uno?

Comment: yes i am usin arduino uno

Comment: @Muhammed, in that case, you will need to use PWM pins on arduino to simulation Serial protocol. Your first code should work since you are using PWM pins 10,11. What I have noticed is that HC-05 does not like SoftwareSerial library. I had to end up using the RX/TX on arduino instead of SoftwareSerial. HC-06 on the other hand, has no problems working with this library.

Comment: yes it is working with arduino RX/TX pin thanks

Comment: @Muhammed, I am glad that worked. please mark the answer as 'Answered' when you get a moment. thanks